# Second Fundamental Theorem

Tags: calculus

If $F(x)=\int\limits_{x^{1/3}}^{2015} 12\sin(t^6) dt$, find the derivative of $F(x)$.

I know I need to use the second fundamental theorem, but I do not know how to apply it to this integral because of the $t^6$ term. If it were just $\sin{t}$, it would be easy. How do I evaluate this? Please don't just type out the answer; just give hints :) Thanks!

Comment: It is much simpler to use the first fundamental theorem of calculus directly. The second part is used for evaluation of the integral and not for evaluation of the derivative of the integral.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this: $F(x) = G(2015)-G(x^{1/3})$, where $G(t) = \int 12\sin(t^6)\,\mathrm{d}t$ (which implies that $G'(t) = 12\sin(t^6)$). Can you see how to get the rest of the answer from here?